# Does community market bought items count as "spending money in-game"?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

When i am buying items(skins and whatnot) in the CS:GO-market in Steam, does it count towards me getting new Steam trading cards by "spending money in-game"?

Comment: I *think* only counts when you buy from the Shop inside the game, not on Market (where you are actually at Steam's website, not ingame). Gotta confirm that.

Comment: Yeah, but you can access the market inside the game.

Comment: I assume you're talking about Dota 2 or TF2?  In CS:GO you get cards just for owning the game, it is not a free-to-play game...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No it doesn't**,as you can see below I bought only one item on **in-game store** for 0.75€(it is 1.04$ now but it was **0.96$** then).

I also bought  ~5€ of items from **community market**,which all together should be **~7$**,but the progress towards the trading card only counts that i spent 0.96$.

[image]